# How do not push ".env" file to the Github repository?

Tags: github, heroku, environment-variables, production-environment

I deployed my fullstack application in *heroku* and now I just want to push my code to github, but **without ".env"** file, because it contains secret information about my database and more.
What can I do in this situation, I just want to show my code to others so I want to push my code in github.

Problem is that *heroku* needs ".env", without this file my application cannot access to the database, but I want to push my code in github, that other people can watch my code.

Sorry if this question looks dumb

Comment: Add the file/extension to .gitignore

Comment: But in that case heroku will not have ".env" file, so application cannot access to the database

Comment: For Heroku, you need to manually configure the environment variables for your app. Here's a helpful link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @rgvlee, ignoring a tracked file has no effect. OP would also have to untrack the file, e.g. by running `git rm --cached .env` (incidentally, since `.env` files shouldn't be committed, that would be a good move here).